# Swift - Jigsaw Snap to Place

Tags: ios, swift

So I am developing an Ipad app that allows the user to solve a jigsaw puzzle. I've worked out getting the panning motion for each piece, but getting them where I want to has not worked properly. I am trying to make a piece snap into it's final destination when it's within a small range, which is followed by a clicking sound.

Here is a bit of code for a single puzzle piece. When my new game button is pressed, an Image View gets set to the corresponding picture, and randomly placed on the canvas.

```
@IBAction func NewGameTapped(sender: UIButton){    
    let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let height = bounds.size.height
    let width = bounds.size.width

    image1.image = UIImage(named:"puzzleImage1.png")
    image1.center.x = CGFloat(100 + arc4random_uniform(UInt32(width)-300))
    image1.center.y = CGFloat(100 + arc4random_uniform(UInt32(height)-300))

    //Create Panning (Dragging) Gesture Recognizer for Image View 1
    let panRecognizer1 = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePanning1:")

    // Add Panning (Dragging) Gesture Recognizer to Image View 1
    image1.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer1)
}
```

This is where I am having some issues.

```
func handlePanning1(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let center = dict1_image_coordinates["puzzleImage1"] as![Int]



    let newTranslation: CGPoint = recognizer.translationInView(image1)

    recognizer.view?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(lastTranslation1.x + newTranslation.x, lastTranslation1.y + newTranslation.y)

    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        lastTranslation1.x += newTranslation.x
        lastTranslation1.y += newTranslation.y
    }

    checkPosition(image1, center: center)
}

func checkPosition(image: UIImageView, center: [Int]){
    let distance: Double = sqrt(pow((Double(image.center.x) - Double(center[0])),2) + pow((Double(image.center.y) - Double(center[1])),2))

    //if the distance is within range, set image to new location.
    if distance <= 20{
        image.center.x = CGFloat(center[0])
        image.center.y = CGFloat(center[1])

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(clickSoundID)

    }
```

For whatever reason, the puzzle piece only wants to snap to it's spot when the piece begins the game within the acceptable snap distance. I have tried checking for the object position in various different parts of my program, but nothing has worked so far. Any help or other tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely caused by this line

```
image1.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer1)
```

Usually people add gestureRecognizer on the parentView, or the rootView of the view controller instead of the image1 itself. The benefit is that the parentView never moves, where as the image1 is constantly being transformed, which may or may not affect the `recognizer.translationInView(x)` method return value.

do this instead:

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer1)
```

and change to this line in `handlePanning1` function:

```
image1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(lastTranslation1.x + newTranslation.x, lastTranslation1.y + newTranslation.y)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention there are many puzzle pieces that need to be moved around, so when tried using the self.view version, it only registered the last set gesture recognizer.

Comment: That's fine zhauck. You can set the number of simultaneous touch's to more than one. Then use the use the recognizer object to find the view to see which jigsaw piece was touched